# Cannot even convert apache.dsw project files

Tags: windows, apache, visual-studio, compilation

I try to compile apache http server 2.4 with visual-studio 2015-2012-2010-2008
express versions. I include apr project files under srclib directory. My platform is win 8.1 64bit.

> From the definition :
>
> Apache can also be compiled using VC++'s Visual Studio development environment. To simplify this process, a Visual Studio workspace, Apache.dsw, is provided. This workspace exposes the entire list of working .dsp projects that are required for the complete Apache binary release. It includes dependencies between the projects to assure that they are built in the appropriate order.

I unzipped the apache server files under c:\httpd-2.4.20\

I convert, compile and use functionality of apr project(separately) with visual-studio 2015 succesfully before.

I always get the error for all included apache projects except apr projects.

`Unable to convert project. Please make sure this is a valid Visual C++ 6.0 project.   Project upgrade failed.
Converting project file 'C:\httpd-2.4.20\support\ab.dsp'. 
// or other dsp files except apr projects`

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue today. It turns out that dsp/dsw files downloaded using SVN have Unix line endings (LF). However Visual Studio doesn't support such a format and all these files should be converted to Windows line endings (CRLF) format. It could be done by [dos2unix](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/) util (the archive from the link contains unix2dos.exe).